Pynput not logging alphanumerical keys on Mac
I want to detect when I press the "space" bar key using python and pynput.
I tried their documentation, my old code but nothing works anymore on MacOS 15.1.1. Even running the script using sudo, adding Visual Studio Code and Terminal app to the whitelist for Input Monitoring and Accessibility it still logs only the control and the command keys.
Here's the code I used (from the docs at https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard)
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()


After restarting my Mac it suddenly worked. So I guess using sudo + input monitoring permissions on IDE and terminal works fine :)
